# Extracting value from XML using Python ElementTree and XPath

Tags: python, xpath, elementtree

I am trying to parse an xml document using Python `ElementTree` with `xpath`. However, I am unable to retrieve the `Address -> Office` tag value.  The number of `Customer` tags may vary from record to record and the `Address --> Office` tag may be  absent for few (`Message`) records.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <Message>
        <title>NewMessage1</title>
        <code>LC208</code>
        <Policy>
           <Customer>
                <id>1234</id>
                <name>John</name>
                <Address>
                   <Office>New York</Office>
                </Address>
          </Customer>
          <Customer>
                <id>7891</id>
                <name>Mike</name>
                <Address>
                   <Office>Chicago</Office>
                </Address>
          </Customer>
      </Policy>
  </Message>
    <Message>
        <title>NewMessage2</title>
        <code>PQ120</code>
        <Policy>
           <Customer>
                <id>5378</id>
                <name>Peter</name>
                <Address>
                   <Office>SFO</Office>
                </Address>
          </Customer>
      </Policy>
  </Message>
</data>
```

From the above xml how can I automate to generate the following:

```
[('NewMessage1', 'LC208', 1234, 'John', 'New York'),
 ('NewMessage1', 'LC208', 7891, 'Mike', 'Chicago'),
 ('NewMessage2', 'PQ120', 5378, 'Peter', 'SFO')]
```

My try:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse("myfile.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

for msg in root.findall("Message"):
    print(msg.find("title").text)
    print(msg.find("code").text)
    for sub in msg.iterfind("./Policy/Customer"):
        print(sub.find("name").text)
        print(sub.find("./Address/Office").text)    <<--- Unable to retrieve
```

I am unable to pick the "./Address/Office" value.

### ######################################################
UPDATE:

I am using the same logic as above for the below xml, but can't extract the value "Ratio" -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:Trigger xlmns:ns0="xxx.xxxxxxx.xx:AM:Trigger">
<Message>
    <MessageItemID>12345</MessageItemID>
    <SourceName>EURO</SourceName>
    <SenderID>ORA5567</SenderID>
    <MessageID>Z823R89K</MessageID>
    <Sender>
        <ID>2121334</ID>
        <Transfer>H01</Transfer>
    </Sender>
    <Policy>
        <PolicyID>PIU7255</PolicyID>
        <Customer>
              <CustomerID>JUW</CustomerID>
              <SFCInd>F</SFCInd>
              <EndDate>2022-05-15</EndDate>
              <Span>6</Span>
              <PaidSpan>TRUE</PaidSpan>
              <YTD>
                 <Ratio>3.5</Ratio>
                 <CustomerAge>45</CustomerAge>
                 <StartDate>2022-03-12</StartDate>
              </YTD>
       </Customer>
   <MessageLedger>
      <TransferCode>LLU</TransferCode>
   </MessageLedger>
   </Policy>
</Message>
</ns0:Trigger>
```

Trying to extract `<YTD> --> <Ratio>` but getting None instead of `3.5`. Not sure where I'm going wrong:

```
tree = ET.parse("file.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
for msg in root.findall("Message"):
    print(msg.find("MessageItemID").text)
    for rec in msg.iterfind("Policy/Customer"):
        print(rec.find("YTD/Ratio").text)
```

I am unable to extract the value `Ratio = 3.5` as it is returning `None`

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Your code works fine for me. It returns
NewMessage1
LC208
John
New York
Mike
Chicago
NewMessage2
PQ120
Peter
SFO

Comment: hi @gimix I am trying to apply the same logic to another xml very similar in form with the  previous one (Question updated pls check). But I am unable to extract the `Ratio`. Not sure where I'm going wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well, it seems there's a problem with your namespace definition (perhaps you are using the namespace before defining it?) but once I changed the root tag to just `<Trigger>` the code worked as expected and I got the `Ratio` value. Is it possible that the issue is somewhere else in your actual code?

Comment: @gimix thanks a ton for your help. I tried out your advice and it worked ! However, as far as the actual code is concerned, it just reads the input xml file uses the same `for` loop that I have posted in my question, to print out the values. My code doesn't do any processing using the `namespace`. Do you mean the input file itself is not correct ? meaning the process that is generating the input file is generating it incorrectly ? I apologize for my naivety regarding `namespace`, but could you please provide me some pointers which I can research further. Thanks.

Comment: you may for example have a look at the [Mozilla Namespaces Crash Course](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course). Or, of course, the [W3C Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names11/)

Comment: Please ask about one problem at a time. You have posted two XML files (and two code snippets), one with a namespace and one without.